# Having trouble pushing up my projects to GitHub

Tags: github

I am having difficulty pushing up my code to GitHub.

I have a GitHub account and have created the repo:

1. cd into project folder
2. git init
   Result:
   Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/blakeflowers/Documents/fake-news-app/.git/
3. git remote add origin https://github.com/devnoob-flowers/shit-they-say.git
   Result:
   fatal: remote origin already exists.
4. git add .
   Results: seems to do nothing
5. git commit -m "Practice Push"
   Results:
   On branch master
   nothing to commit, working tree clean
6. git push -u origin master
   To https://github.com/devnoob-flowers/shit-they-say.git
   ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/devnoob-flowers/shit-they-say.git'
   hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
   hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
   hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
   hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

So clearly I have no idea what the heck is going on.

Once again im trying to push my code up to GitHub and eventually deploy the site using Github pages. just something im doing for practice.

Comment: The error message explains it very well: There are new additional commits in the remote repository. To get them into the local repository, you have to execute the command `git pull`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by finding some terminal code but I don't understand it. Can anyone explain?

This solved my problem:

```sh
git fetch origin master:tmp
git rebase tmp
git push origin HEAD:master
git branch -D tmp
```

Comment: You create a new tmp branch locally and download the master branch of the remote origin repository to the local tmp branch. You [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/de/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) the tmp branch. And at the end you push your changes to the remote repository and delete the tmp branch.